# Не могу избавиться от ошибки в консоли, которая никак не влияет на работу приложения: Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reactcsstransitiongroup

Всем привет! Использую React Transition Group для анимации. Анимация работает, но появляется ошибка. Что бы ёе устранить пробовал всякие варианты передачи ref, но всё тщетно.

Вот компонент который рендерит список дел:

```
import React from "react";
import ToDoItem from "./ToDoItem/ToDoItem";
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";
import "./ToDoList.css";

function ToDoList({ todos, actions }) {
 return todos.length > 0 ? (
   <div className="container_list">
     <TransitionGroup component='ul' className="todo_list_inner">
       {todos.map((todo) => {
         return (
           <CSSTransition  key={todo.id} timeout={700} classNames="li">
             <ToDoItem  todo={todo} id={todo.id} {...actions} />
           </CSSTransition>
         );
       })}
     </TransitionGroup>
   </div>
 ) : (
   <h1 className="emptyList">Пустой список дел...</h1>
 );}

export default ToDoList;
```

И вот компонент ToDoItem

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, memo } from "react";
import Input from "../../UI/Input/Input";
import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";
import "./ToDoItem.css"

function ToDoItem({ todo, completeTodo, deleteTodo, id, editTodo}) {
  const [editing, editingState] = useState(false);
  const [editInputValue, editInputValueState] = useState("");
  const classes = [];
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editing) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  });

  const changeTitle = () => {
    editingState(true);
    editInputValueState(todo.title); 
  };

  const changeComplite =() => {
    completeTodo(id);
  }

  if (todo.completed) {
    classes.push("done");
  }

  const removeTodo = () => {
    deleteTodo(todo.id);
  };

  const changeValue = (event) => {
    editInputValueState(event.target.value);
  };

  const submitUpdate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    editTodo(id, editInputValue);
    editingState(false);
    editInputValueState("");
  };

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    editTodo(id, e.target.value);
    editingState(false);
    editInputValueState("");
  };

  const todoItemInputEdit = () => {
    return (
      <form
        className="form_todoItem"
        onSubmit={submitUpdate}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      >
        <Input value={editInputValue} onChange={changeValue} ref={inputRef} />
      </form>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <li className='liTodo'>
        <span className={classes.join(" ")}>
          <Input
            type="checkbox"
            id={id}
            checked={todo.completed}
            onChange={changeComplite}
          />
          &nbsp;
          {editing ? todoItemInputEdit() : todo.title}
        </span>
        <div className="btn_todoItem">
          <Button
            text={String.fromCharCode(9998)}
            className="btn_edit"
            onClick={changeTitle}
          />
          <Button
            className="btnRemove"
            onClick={removeTodo}
            text={String.fromCharCode(215)}
          />
        </div>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}

export default memo(ToDoItem);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903335/warning-finddomnode-is-deprecated-in-strictmode-finddomnode-was-passed-an-inst

Answer (score 0):

Это strict мод

```
import { StrictMode } from 'react'

export const App = () => (
  <StrictMode>
    <div>
      {/* code */}
    </div>
  </StrictMode>
)
```

А это решение проблемы

```
export const App = () => (
    <div>
      {/* code */}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: разве это выход?  строгий режим помогает избежать многих ошибок,  поэтому он и был придуман. нужно как то решить проблему со strickMode

Comment: Это не выход, это решение. Обычно невозможно обойтись, потому что сторонние скрипты не все написаны под strict mode.
А решение: не использовать такие скрипты, или же если свой код, его можно легко переписать.
finddomnode  deprecated на strict mode  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode